# Draggable UI in jQuery

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery-ui, draggable

I am currently working on a project where I need to go for draggable elements. There will be list of options e.g. Sunday, Monday, Tuesday... Saturday. Here user will be selecting any of them, say Sunday, Wednesday, Saturday. I need to display them in such a way the user can realign them in any Order.

E.g

```
Sunday
Saturday
Wednesday
```

or

```
Sunday
Wednesday
Saturday
```

And I need to get the display order in my Client/ Server side

I have decided to provided asp checkboxs for the parent list. When user checks any of the option, I need to populate it in another UI which would later helps me to realign the selected options. I have gone through few samples of draggable jQuery UI but not sure which will suit my requirement.

Can any one suggest the BEST?

Comment: Why would jQuery UI draggable not be ok?

Comment: I am sorry! jQuery UI draggable+ sortable didn't fall into my search list when i searched in Google

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should be enough for you:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#sortable

Also, I would suggest not using the checkboxes but adding another draggable component that marks the limit between used and unused days, like:

```
> Saturday
> Sunday
> **Below are ignored**
> ...
```

I think it may be more usable.

Comment: Thats Great..! Do you mean to have another draggable Component A (parent with all options) from which I'll drag the required to another draggable component B (child with required days)?

Comment: That, or just have all in the same component and a bar that divides the elements in "wanted" and "not wanted", depending if they are above or below it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this project helps you

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

Also you can find samples on these links

http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/wp-content/uploads/file/jquerydragdrop/

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/drag-to-share/

http://tutorialzine.com/2009/09/shopping-cart-php-jquery/

http://www.isocra.com/2008/02/table-drag-and-drop-jquery-plugin/